# Converting integers to Int8Arrays and getting them to echo properly on the JavaScript command-line

Tags: javascript, hex, arraybuffer

In JavaScript I have an array of integers. I would like to get the hex value of each of these integers into a Int8Array and echo these values to the console.

For the following code, the console echoes `[8, 5, 4, 4, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`when I expected `[89,50,4E,47,...]`

```
var data = [137,80,78,71]; // equals 0x89,0x50,0x4E,0x47
var hexValueArrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer((data.length+1)*2);
var hexValueInt8Ary = new Int8Array(hexValueArrayBuffer);

var ixx=0;
for(var index in data){
    var hexValue = data[index].toString(16);
    hexValueInt8Ary.set(hexValue,ixx++);

    console.log("Added "+hexValue);
    if(ixx==data.length){
           console.log(hexValueInt8Ary);
    }
}
```

From this, it seems that only the first nibble of each expected result is added. What can I do to get the expected result of:

```
[89,50,4E,47,...]
```

Answer (score 2):

Int8Arrays just store integers (independently of the base) -- but you are trying to store strings. Just store the values directly. You can convert them to hex when you read them, but the base is never a part of the values.

```
var data = [137,80,78,71]; // equals 0x89,0x50,0x4E,0x47
var hexValueArrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer((data.length+1)*2);  // Why twice the size?
var hexValueInt8Ary = new Int8Array(hexValueArrayBuffer);

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  hexValueInt8Ary.set[i] = data[i];  // you could use set to set all values at once
  var hexValue = hexValueInt8Ary[i].toString(16);

  console.log("Added "+hexValue);
}
console.log(hexValueInt8Ary);
```

}